# How to display rainbow message in console.log

Tags: javascript, css, colors, console.log

Hi have a script for rainbowtizing console.log output.

When i try, console.log output raw string, but if i copy this output in another console.log, he output the message with the correct color.

Do you know why ?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
 var inputValue = input.value;
 var inputSplitted = inputValue.split("");
 
 let i = 0,
  inputLength = inputSplitted.length;
 var newLog ='"';
 var colors = "";
 for(i=0; i<inputLength; i++){
  // Chaque lettre est contenue dans inputSplitted[i]
  newLog += "%c"+inputSplitted[i];
  colors += ',"color: '+randomColor()+';"';
 }
 newLog +='"';
 var log = newLog+colors;
 console.log(log);
 console.log("%ch%ce%cl%cl%co%c %cw%co%cr%cl%cd","color: #144143;","color: #40C71F;","color: #5B7487;","color: #E3E226;","color: #6A8693;","color: #EC8802;","color: #9D44DE;","color: #1F1C4D;","color: #92812D;","color: #7A412C;","color: #73936F;");
});

function randomColor() {
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
 var color = '#';
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
 }
 return color;
}
```

```html
<input type=text name=input id=input>
```

Comment: In the first console.log you have a string and in the second you have multiple strings separated by `,`. So the second console.log handles them as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is said in the comment the browser handles the string just as a string and not as parameters.

You have to declare an array and use `console.log.apply`.

Have a look:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
 var inputValue = input.value;
 var inputSplitted = inputValue.split("");
 
 let i = 0,
  inputLength = inputSplitted.length;
 var newLog ='';
 var colors = "";
 for(i=0; i<inputLength; i++){
  // Chaque lettre est contenue dans inputSplitted[i]
  newLog += "%c"+inputSplitted[i];
  colors += '||color: '+randomColor()+';';
 }
 newLog +='';
 var log = newLog+colors;
 var arr = log.split('||');
 console.log.apply(console, arr);
 console.log("%ch%ce%cl%cl%co%c %cw%co%cr%cl%cd","color: #144143;","color: #40C71F;","color: #5B7487;","color: #E3E226;","color: #6A8693;","color: #EC8802;","color: #9D44DE;","color: #1F1C4D;","color: #92812D;","color: #7A412C;","color: #73936F;");
});



function randomColor() {
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
 var color = '#';
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
 }
 return color;
}
```

```html
<input type=text name=input id=input>
```

Hope this code will help you. :)